# How can I make contract with BRC20?

Tags: deployment, blockchain, bitcoin, nft, contract

I'm going to develop DApp Game based on BRC20.
But I don't know how to make contract and deployment with BRC20, because BRC20 was created a few months ago.
It's very difficult for me to find out reasonable information related to BRC20, even via internet.
So I really need your help.
Thanks.

Because of the lack of experience on BRC20, I can't begin to make contracts and deployment.
Furthermore, I don't know what kind of language does it use.
Some people say that, BRC20 contract is built by JS/TS, and others say it use Go.
But I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

BRC20 doesn't support contracts. It's not like etherium. There is no virtual machine. There is no gas. BRC20 is simply saying "This satoshi represents something" and then keeping track of that satoshi with special wallet software. That's it. There are no contracts. There is no virtual machine that runs code.